# Preview url is not showing correctly when all metadata are ok

Tags: facebook-graph-api, metadata, preview

Hello from today we begin to have a problem with the metadata, nothing added to level code, and nothing change  in this side, normally we had preview of the page based in the metadata , all params are ok, og:image  path is ok and all other meta params have been verified but looks how that there are some problem that i not arrive to see :

https://www.onehousestand.com/fr/salles/Brabant-Flamand/Affligem/dans-le-loft-la-maison-de-laura

If i look into all params are ok, but by example into facebook developer console  'https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/' i have this error : 
Unknown Image Error
We have detected an unknown error in the "og: image" property (URL https://www.onehousestand.com/images/5/s_58.jpg).

But img is ok and path is ok
In the page, the https path to image was changed, if we look the source code of the page, no https in the path to og:image really but facebook detect that yes (i dont know if possible cache)

All ideas and suggestions are wellcome

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.onehousestand.com%2Ffr%2Fsalles%2FBrabant-Flamand%2FAffligem%2Fdans-le-loft-la-maison-de-laura - the Facebook scraper only gets presented with your 404 error document. So go figure out what causes _your_ system to behave that way.

Comment: Some idea, because how you can see if you do request to url, is working ok , then i dont undestood why if we try request from external sources always give this

Comment: some idea? because how you see, if we do request over url, all is ok, problem is when external sources try read, and not updates in code to metatag level have been added